# how to combine two video streams in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I have two video cameras and I can get an image from then use 'rtspsrc'.
But I want to combine the video streams from these cameras

I realized that it is necessary to use videomixer, but I dont understand how.
I can find this code to combine two streams into one
gst-launch-1.0 
videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=50 sink_1::ypos=50 sink_2::xpos=400 sink_2::ypos=50  
! x264enc 
! rtph264pay 
! udpsink host=localhost port=5000 
videotestsrc pattern=white 
! video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=5/1, width=740, height=480 
! m. 
videotestsrc pattern=red 
! videobox left=100 
! video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=5/1, width=300, height=200 
! queue 
! m. 
videotestsrc pattern=green 
! videobox left=500 
! video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=5/1, width=300, height=200 
! queue 
! m.
But I don't understand why there are three sources here and how to change this code for my task
I work in Windows on powershell